Is intuitionistic mathematics situated in time?
Mathematics, or at least classical mathematics (that is, mathematics based on classical logic), is thought to be timeless. A theorem that is proven to be true in classical mathematics was true always and will be true forever. But what about intuitionistic mathematics? Is it situated in time? Let me explain what I mean. Suppose at time T it is not known by mathematicians whether or not a particular sequence S of decimal digits occurs in the number pi. Then, in intuitionistic mathematics, the statement "S occurs in pi OR S does not occur in pi" is not a theorem. However, suppose at some later time T' it is known that S does occur in pi. Then, suddenly, "S occurs in pi OR S does not occur in pi" becomes a theorem. So, then, is intuitionistic mathematics situated in time, unlike classical mathematics? Or am I misunderstanding intuitionism? I would also love to know what philosophers of mathematics have written about this matter.

See Why do constructive mathematicians claim that mathematical truth is temporal? as well as Brower's Intuitionism.

See also Palle Yourgrau, Proof vs Provability: On Brouwer’s Time Problem (History and Philosophy of Logic, 2020)

According to Kant time is the purest form of intuition underlying the most general category making mathematics possibly sensible, even more pure than space in many senses, so all mathematics under his view could be said to be situated or based on time and in particular intuitionistic mathematics is simply situated on additional considerations such as constructability and precaution due to human mind's limitations...

"classical" truth is tensless but form the point of view of Intuitionism, we may assert that a proposition is true only when we have a proof of it. Thus, where "lives" a proposition that has not yet been proved? According to Martin-Löf, it can be useful to speak of actual and potential truth of a proposition: the latter one explained by the notion of the potential existence of a proof. A proof of a proposition A exists actually only when A has been proved. 1/2

A proposition that has been proved becomes actually true, but it was potentially true even before having been proved, and it would be true even if, in fact, it had never been proved. In this way, according to Martin-Löf, we can overcome the objection that saying that a proposition becomes true just when it is
proved is counterintuitive and in conflict with the "common sense" use of the truth predicate. 2/2

If we agree with it, we have to adopt an epistemic approach (instead of the Platonist one) where the "time" factor is relevant.

This blog post argues that Intuitionistic / constructivist logic indeed involves time:

I am reaching the conclusion that it is not the non-canonicity of the law of excluded middle that is the locus of non-constructivity.  It is the lack of a notion of the progression of time ...
[C]lassical logic is the language of mathematics, where everything is considered as a static entity (notwithstanding the fact that dynamic entities like computations can be statically described).  Constructive logic is supposed to have a dynamic character: it should capture the idea, somehow, that the state of information can change over time.


The cited approach is flawed, for every theorem of intuitionistic logic is a theorem of classical logic verbatim. The actual distinction is explained via De Morgan's relations; quoting WP: "[~(P & Q) → ((~P | ~Q))] does not hold in pure intuitionistic logic. That is, the failure of the joint proposition P & Q cannot necessarily be resolved to the failure of either of the two conjuncts."

This seems to have little to do with intuitionism: you happened to pick a statement of the form A ∨ ¬A, but you could instead replace it with the statement of the Riemann hypothesis and conclude that classical mathematics is "situated in time", by the same argument. What you are really saying is that human knowledge is situated in time (which is obvious), even if the facts we have knowledge of are timeless.
There is a sense in which constructive mathematics is related to time, namely Kripke semantics. A Kripke model can be thought of as a (not necessarily linear) sequence of worlds, which one may interpret as the state of the world evolving over time. This generalises to semantics in (pre)sheaf topoi; the objects of the presheaf topos on ω^op are sometimes called "time-dependent sets". Kripke models can be used to give counterexamples to statements like A ∨ ¬A, by designing "branching" sequences of worlds where A becomes true in one branch and false in the other.

This answer fails to take into account the unique characterization of truth in intuitionistic mathematics that the question is asking about.

What are you referring to, @DavidGudeman?

Brouwer's logic has been described as such that "true" means "has been proven". In other words, it can be understood in such a way that a theorem can go from being false to being true because a proof is found. This may or may not be a fair description of his logic, but that is what the question is about.

@DavidGudeman - not "from false to true", but "from unknown to true". A false statement is a statement for which we have a proof of its absurdity: so that proof cannot turn to be a "positive" proof.

@DavidGudeman that seems like a possible interpretation of the question, but it is not mine. Notice that the question doesn't mention truth, and I don't think it is based on any preconceptions of what Brouwer's logic "has been described as".

@MauroALLEGRANZA, fair enough.

It does mention theoremhood: "However, suppose at some later time T' it is known that S does occur in pi. Then, suddenly, 'S occurs in pi OR S does not occur in pi' becomes a theorem."

@DavidGudeman: Theoremhood doesn't vary in time, nor do the digits of pi. The BHK interpretation, which takes place with respect to a computer which evolves in time, should not be confused with the formal syntax of intuitionistic logic.

@Corbin, Please pay attention to the quote marks. I never said that theoremhood varies in time.

Brower's philosophy is a bit of an extreme, where he conceives "time" as the one category that is analytic a priori (as opposed to the Kantian "time" and "space").  But otherwise intuitionism, as well as constructivism, just like mathematics and even logic in general, do not need the notion of time: it is a process or a construction, where the "steps" are logical, not temporal, just like with a mathematical sequence...
